# Why did I get gifted a dozen or more cars last night/this morning?

Tags: forza-motorsport-3

Not that I'm looking a gift horse in the mouth, I'm just curious. Last night I was playing Forza Motorsport 3, and decided to start getting serious with the season play mode. (I'd done most of my events -- getting to level 50 and a very nice stable of rides -- in the event list.)

I wrapped up season 1, then went to read about Forza 4.

This morning, I'm sick at home, and decide to make myself feel better by knocking out some of season 2. Then I notice my little message indicator. Gift cars. Lots of them. I've lost count, to be honest, but I'm still downloading them. Some were cars I'm sure I never saw in the game yet, like a Shelby GT500KR. Others I already owned. Many were R-series or higher. Most are decked out in sweet race livery, including several branded as Turn 10 or Forza Motorsport cars.

Is all this because I finished season 1 at all gold? (And if so, can I expect even more as I finish the later seasons?) Or was there some other reason Turn 10 gifted me at least a dozen rides?

(I do own all of the available DLC cars, with the exception of the Stig pack, because I'm not shelling out for "ultimate" just for that. That said, I didn't get the VIP pack until last night -- perhaps that may have had something to do with it as well?)

Comment: Maybe it's a bribe to keep in your favor and avoid your ire? I mean, when you're a mass murderer, word about your exploits is *bound* to go around.

Answer (score 1):

You get a car for every level, and as far as i can tell that seems to be the only reason, so you probably got one from levels 1 to 50 just didn't notice the gift cars.

Comment: No, I'd gotten those all already. But good guess. I'm beginning to think it's due to buying the VIP pack -- I also noticed a crown next to my gamer tag now, where previously there wasn't ...